# Why call back function is not working on marker setting in leaflet library Android?

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, leaflet, leaflet.draw

In my app, I am using leaflet library to render map and drawing shapes. I am using below code to set marker on the map. Markers are setting properly bu clicking on those marker icon is not working. I mean callback function is not being called.
Below is the code I am using for my case.

```
var marker = L.marker([lat, lng], 
{ name: dr.Description, clickable: true, icon: vehicleIconBasisOnTrip }).
    addTo(markerVehicleLayer).on('click',function()
    {$scope.getVehicleDetails(dr)}
    )
```

One thing I want to mention is that, I have tested the same code that is working fine on Android lollipop version and when tried pre lollipop version call back function is not calling. And there is nothing in console when I attached device to the browser. Any help.

Answer (score 1):

After spending a lot of time, I am able to resolve the problem. In the div of map I added 'data-tap-disabled="true"'. Below is the code.

```
<div id="map-div" class="map-style" data-tap-disabled="true">
```